# WearableListenerService onCreate() never called

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-2.0

A bug has cropped up recently in one of my Wear OS (Android Wear)-enabled apps whereby the Service on the mobile device never reacts when the wearable sends it data.

While troubleshooting the root cause, I've noted that the **onCreate()** method of **WearableListenerService** is never called. Likewise, the **onStartCommand()** method from the Service superclass is never called, which I take to mean the Service is indeed not running.

The Service is defined in **AndroidManifest.xml**, so I can't understand why it's not running anymore.

Below are some code snippets from a new project, where all I do is define a **WearableListenerService** and try to get it to start. Note that this is to define a Service which runs on a **mobile** device:

**WearMessageListenerService.java**

```
package com.example.test.wearlistenertest;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.wearable.WearableListenerService;

public class WearMessageListenerService extends WearableListenerService {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Log.v("test", "onCreate()");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.v("test", "onStartCommand()");

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test.wearlistenertest">

    <application
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name="com.example.test.wearlistenertest.WearMessageListenerService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.MESSAGE_LISTENER" />
                <data android:scheme="wear" android:host="*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test.wearlistenertest"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:11.8.0'
}
```

Neither of the **Log.v()** methods above output anything on run. I've tested on API 23 and 27.

I'd really appreciate some help with this, as I can't understand why I can't get a basic Service to start. I'm happy to provide any additional details. Many thanks in advance for any assistance offered. - Aaron

Comment: Are your messages from the watch app being received? If not, then this isn't really about the `onCreate()` method, and perhaps you should post the code you're using to send messages from the watch.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like your manifest declaration of the message receiver is wrong. Here's one that's working from one of my apps:

```
<service android:name=".MyMessageListener"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.MESSAGE_RECEIVED" />
        <data android:host="*" android:scheme="wear"
              android:pathPrefix="@string/wear_path_prefix"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Specifically, note that the `action` should end in `MESSAGE_RECEIVED` (your manifest has `MESSAGE_LISTENER` instead). I think that's the key problem, but exporting the service and adding a `pathPrefix` are probably good ideas too.